# Communication between two nodes

Tags: networking, network-programming, network-protocols, decoding

I have an assignment to implementation of communication between 2 PC terminals using Ethernet.

There is no big deal in establishing network between 2 nodes. but the the big deal is "**8 bit data sent on one node is to be decoded on the other node & the same is to be displayed & if possible though a front end window."** 
the specs for the front end window on the receiving node is as follows , say for example 10110101 is sent from node 1 , the same is to be decoded & interpreted as below using a frontend GUI window , A-On 
                     B-off
                     C-On
                     D-On
                     E-Off
                     F-On
                     G-Off
                     H-On
So please someone suggest me is any other application available to see the decoding process on terminal or what are the steps i need to intiate.

All your suggestions are appreciated,
Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 0):

I guess your specific solution depends on if you are allowed to use existing libraries. Either way I would checkout [networkComms.net](https://bitbucket.org/MarcF/networkcomms.net), an open source network library written in C#.

You could achieve your basic goal if you modify the basic send example (11 lines of code) [here](https://bitbucket.org/MarcF/networkcomms.net/src/f3b381a83669/ExamplesConsole/BasicSend.cs). Instead of sending a random string, send your 8 bits, and on the receiving end, rather than just writing the string to the console do something cleverer:

```
if (recievedString == "10110101")
{
 //Do this
}
else
{
 //Do this instead
}
```

If you are not allowed to use existing libraries and have to write something from scatch perhaps networkComms.net could act as a good guide?